# How to change title of java database application in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

When creating a database application in Netbeans. How do I change the default title in the title bar?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the Project Name, and select `Rename`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project. Select Properties -> Application and the title and other application information is there to be edited.